# On monkey-patching a third-party function

Tags: customize, advice

The following snippet, featuring the "fantasy function" `clone-function`, illustrates what I'd like to do:

```
(defvar last-enabled-foo nil)

;; hold on to a "clone"/copy of third-party function enable-foo
(defvar original-enable-foo (clone-function 'enable-foo))

;; replace enable-foo with a wrapper function around it
;; module foo.el
(defun enable-foo (foo)
  (setq last-enabled-foo foo)
  (funcall original-enable-foo foo))
```

Basically, `clone-function` ensures that `original-enable-foo` refers to a function that is completely distinct from the newly defined `enable-foo`.

How could one implement `clone-function`?

Comment: Are you familiar with emacs function advice and not using it for a specific purpose? If you aren't aware, advice is how this sort of thing should be handled. https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For variety, here's a solution using the `:around` advice.

Copy the below test snippet to the *scratch* buffer and evaluate the `progn` form.

```el
(progn
  (defvar last-enabled-foo nil)
  (setq last-enabled-foo nil)

  (defun enable-foo (foo)
    (message "last-enabled-foo = %S" last-enabled-foo))

  (defun adv/enable-foo (orig-fun &rest args)
    (setq last-enabled-foo args)
    (apply orig-fun args))
  (advice-add 'enable-foo :around #'adv/enable-foo)
  ;; Comment the below line to see the advice in effect
  (advice-remove 'enable-foo #'adv/enable-foo)

  (enable-foo 9))
```

---

With the way it is right now, you will always see the output as:

> last-enabled-foo = nil

This is because we are setting the `last-enabled-foo` value to `nil` and the value `9` passed to `enable-foo` is not being assigned to `last-enabled-foo`.

```el
(setq last-enabled-foo nil)
(defun enable-foo (foo)
  (message "last-enabled-foo = %S" last-enabled-foo))
(enable-foo 9)
```

The advice code is ineffective as we are adding an advice and then again removing the same.

---

Now comment out the `(advice-remove ..)` line. **Now** the advice will be in effect and you will see the *magic* when you re-evaluate that same `progn` form.

Now, the output will be:

> last-enabled-foo = (9)

Now, even though the `setq` form is setting the `last-enabled-foo` value to `nil` during each `progn` evaluation, it is being set to the `enable-foo` argument `args` inside the advice function `adv/enable-foo`.

```el
(defun adv/enable-foo (orig-fun &rest args)
  (setq last-enabled-foo args)
  (apply orig-fun args))
```

---

**References:**

- [Advising Emacs Lisp Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html)

  - [Advice Combinators like `:around`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advice-combinators.html#Advice-combinators)
  - [`advice-add` and `advice-remove`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Named-Functions.html#Advising-Named-Functions)

Answer (score 4):

I agree that using advice is probably the way to go, but if you really, truly have to, you can use something like this. (Comments are welcome.)

```el
(defun third-party-func ()
  (message "original"))

(defalias 'third-party-func-original
          (symbol-function 'third-party-func))

(defun third-party-func ()
  (message "new!")
  (third-party-func-original))

; now (third-party-func) calls the patched version;
; (third-party-func-original) calls the original version
```

Comment: I'd use `defalias` instead of `fset`.

Comment: @wasamasa: Do you mind explaining why? (I just learned about `defalias-fset-function` and that `defalias` records which file defined the function (like `defun`, but I have no idea what the implications are.)

Comment: It is all about communicating intent.  The purpose of this example is having an alias of the original function around, so you'd use `defalias` instead of `fset`.  If you were doing something like building [your own flet](https://github.com/nicferrier/emacs-noflet), `fset` would be the more idiomatic choice.

Comment: @wasamasa: Yup. Good point.

Comment: `symbol-function` isn't needed either as both `fset` and `defalias` operate on the function slot.

Comment: @wasamasa: I believe `symbol-function` is needed. In my Emacs (24.5.1) `(defalias 'third-party-func-original third-party-func)` (no quoting) fails with `Lisp error: (void-variable third-party-func)` and `(defalias 'third-party-func-original 'third-party-func)` (quoted) creates an alias using the **symbol** `third-party-func` as the definition, which leads to infinite recursion in the new `third-party-func` and a failure with `Lisp error: (error "Lisp nesting exceeds `max-lisp-eval-depth'")`.

Comment: Meh, looks like a perfect usecase for [noflet](https://github.com/nicferrier/emacs-noflet) then.