# How do I temporarily mock a function for testing?

Tags: testing, dynamic-scoping, monkey-patching

I'd like to patch some elisp functions inside my unit tests. I've tried `cl-labels` and `cl-flet`, but neither achieve the result I want:

```
(defun return-number ()
  1)

(defun calls-return-number ()
  (return-number))

(defun patch-cl-labels ()
  (cl-labels ((return-number () 2))
    (calls-return-number)))

(message "After patching: %s" (patch-cl-labels))
```

I've looked at [monkey-patching a function](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3276/304) (but this permanently changes behaviour) and [patching a third-party function](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/19884/304) (this uses advice and holds on to the old function).

Comment: "*neither achieve the result I want*" - which is not specified here. The question is too broad and unclear.

Comment: What I want is specified in the title: I want to temporarily mock a function. In the example, I want `return-number` to return 2.

Comment: As I said, you do **not** say how your attempts do not achieve the result you want. Clearly, if all you want is for "*`return-number` to return 2*" then `(defun return-number () 2)` achieves that. And as for temporary, just save the original definition (see `symbol-function`) and later restore it (see `fset` or `defalias`). I sense that you want something more or different, but you don't specify what that is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both macros are lexically scoped, that's why they have no effect on the "distant" call.  Either use the deprecated older `flet` or `cl-letf`.

```
(cl-letf (((symbol-function 'return-number)
           (lambda () 2)))
  ...)
```

Comment: Of course, I was confusing with dynamic scope. Thanks.

Comment: `Doom` has a macro wrapper around`cl-letf` named `letf!`.