# How to temporarily change the definition of a function?

Tags: functions, lexical-scoping, dynamic-scoping

In the following code the function `foo` calls the outer `f2` function. How to make it call the anonymous function bound within the `let`?

```el
(defun f2 ()
  (message "outer f2"))

(defun foo ()
  (f2))

(let ((f2 (lambda ()
            (message "inner f2"))))
  (foo)) ;; `foo' does not call `f2' in the `let', i.e. prints "outer f2"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I temporarily mock a function for testing?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/25055/how-do-i-temporarily-mock-a-function-for-testing)

Answer (score 5):

> How to temporarily change the definition of a function?

Calling a function by its (symbol) name means calling that symbol's [function slot](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbol-Components.html).  So, to temporarily change the definition of a function that is called by its name, you need to temporarily modify its [`symbol-function`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Cells.html) value.  The shortest way to do that is with `cl-letf`; see [`(info "(cl) Modify Macros")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Modify-Macros.html).

```el
(eval-when-compile
  (require 'cl-lib))

(defun f2 ()
  (message "outer f2"))

(defun foo ()
  (f2))

(cl-letf (((symbol-function 'f2)
           (lambda () (message "inner f2"))))
  (foo)) ;; => inner f2
```

An alternative, more compositional approach is to use [function advice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html), but to my knowledge there isn't a handy macro for that, and it doesn't provide any benefits in simple cases like the example above.  For example:

```el
(unwind-protect
    (progn
      (advice-add 'f2 :override
                  (lambda () (message "inner f2"))
                  '((name . my-override)))
      (foo))
  (advice-remove 'f2 'my-override)) ;; => inner f2
```